# How can I read the Geometry of IHO S100 products (S123 and S127) geometry (a GML file) in Python?

Tags: python, gdal, geopandas, gml, s-100

I am working on the IHO (International Hydrographic Organization) S100 products, especially, S-123 and S-127. These marine products are the data related to S-123 [Marine Radio Services](https://registry.iho.int/productspec/view.do?idx=74&product_ID=S-123&statusS=5&domainS=ALL&category=product_ID&searchValue=) and S-127 [Marine Traffic Management](https://registry.iho.int/productspec/view.do?idx=175&product_ID=S-127&statusS=5&domainS=ALL&category=product_ID&searchValue=). These data are in fact few layers of points and polygons and ... that are grouped together with few non-geometry layers and are stored in a ***.gml file.

I need to read this file in Python but I have errors and strange geometries using GeoPandas or GDAL.
I used scripts likes this:

```
from osgeo import ogr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd

file_path=r"C:\Users\username\JSNPI123EX_A0001.GML"

# Open the GML file
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('GML')
dataSource = driver.Open(file_path, 0)  

# Loop over the layers
for i in range(dataSource.GetLayerCount()):
    layer = dataSource.GetLayerByIndex(i)
    print(f'Layer {i}: {layer.GetName()}')
    df = gpd.read_file(file_path, layer=layer.GetName()) 
    df.to_crs("EPSG:3979").plot()
    plt.show()
    
    # Loop over the features in each layer
    for feature in layer:
        print(feature.GetFieldCount())
```

I think Since there are other namespaces other than gml, such as s100_profile, s100, and S127 ... I am not able to read these files properly.
I managed to read the descriptive parts using lxml and other xml parsing packages for python, but I have still serious problems with reading the geometry! Since the file is a gml, I thought that the geometries should be 100% inline with gml and the packages should be able to read it but they cannot.
the geometries look like this:

```
<geometry><S100:surfaceProperty><gml:Surface gml:id="SURFACE000">
                <gml:patches>
                    <gml:PolygonPatch><gml:exterior><gml:LinearRing>
                        <gml:posList>55 -36 55 -22 71 -22 71 -36 55 -36</gml:posList>
                    </gml:LinearRing></gml:exterior></gml:PolygonPatch>
                </gml:patches>
            </gml:Surface></S100:surfaceProperty>
            </geometry>
```

or

```
<geometry><!-- Area A -->
            <S100:surfaceProperty><S100:Polygon gml:id="S.RDOSVC.51"><gml:exterior>
                <gml:LinearRing>
                    <gml:posList>60.0 -32.0 65.0 -32.0 65.0 -34.0 60.0 -34.0 60.0 -32.0</gml:posList>
                </gml:LinearRing>
            </gml:exterior></S100:Polygon></S100:surfaceProperty>
        </geometry>
```

or

```
            <geometry>
                <S100:surfaceProperty>
                    <S100:Surface gml:id="NAVARE01.S">
                        <gml:patches>
                            <gml:PolygonPatch>
                                <gml:exterior>
                                    <gml:LinearRing>
                                        <gml:posList>60.7667 -32.6333 60.7667 -32.3167 61.3333 -32.3167 61.3333 -32.6333 60.7667 -32.6333</gml:posList>
                                    </gml:LinearRing>
                                </gml:exterior>
                            </gml:PolygonPatch>
                        </gml:patches>
                    </S100:Surface>
                </S100:surfaceProperty>
            </geometry>
```

How should I read these gml files in python?

An example of S-127 data can be found on [IHO website](https://registry.iho.int/productspec/view.do?idx=175&product_ID=S-127&statusS=5&domainS=ALL&category=product_ID&searchValue=):
[image: Sample S127 Data]
Or this example that is S-123 gml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<S123:Dataset xmlns:S123="http://www.iho.int/S123/gml/1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.iho.int/S-123/gml/1.0 ../../schemas/S123/1.0/20170831/S123.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:S100="http://www.iho.int/s100gml/1.0" xmlns:s100_profile="http://www.iho.int/S-100/profile/s100_gmlProfile" gml:id="TEST002">
    <gml:boundedBy>
        <gml:Envelope srsName="EPSG:4326" srsDimension="2">
            <gml:lowerCorner>60.7667 -32.6333</gml:lowerCorner>
            <gml:upperCorner>61.3333 -32.3167</gml:upperCorner>
        </gml:Envelope>
    </gml:boundedBy>
    <DatasetIdentificationInformation>
        <S100:encodingSpecification>S-100 Part 10b</S100:encodingSpecification>
        <S100:encodingSpecificationEdition>1.0</S100:encodingSpecificationEdition>
        <S100:productIdentifier>S-123</S100:productIdentifier>
        <S100:productEdition>1.0</S100:productEdition>
        <S100:applicationProfile/>
        <S100:datasetFileIdentifier>123KR00GB4X0000__</S100:datasetFileIdentifier>
        <S100:datasetTitle>Radio service information in Jussland</S100:datasetTitle>
        <S100:datasetReferenceDate>2019-08-01</S100:datasetReferenceDate>
        <S100:datasetLanguage>en</S100:datasetLanguage>
        <S100:datasetAbstract>.</S100:datasetAbstract>
        <S100:datasetTopicCategory>oceans</S100:datasetTopicCategory>
    </DatasetIdentificationInformation>
    <DatasetStructureInformation>
        <S100:datasetCoordOriginX>0.0</S100:datasetCoordOriginX>
        <S100:datasetCoordOriginY>0.0</S100:datasetCoordOriginY>
        <S100:datasetCoordOriginZ>0.0</S100:datasetCoordOriginZ>
        <S100:coordMultFactorX>1</S100:coordMultFactorX>
        <S100:coordMultFactorY>1</S100:coordMultFactorY>
        <S100:coordMultFactorZ>1</S100:coordMultFactorZ>
    </DatasetStructureInformation>
    <imember>
        <S123:Authority gml:id="AUTHOR01">
            <featureName>
                <language>eng</language>
                <name>Jussland Met Office</name>
            </featureName>
            <categoryOfAuthority>maritime</categoryOfAuthority>
        </S123:Authority>
    </imember>
    <member>
        <S123:NavigationalMeteorologicalArea gml:id="NAVARE01">
            <textContent>
                <information>
                    <language>eng</language>
                    <text>Transmission of NAVAREA messages for NAVAREA VII (AOR-E) at 0530, 1730</text>
                </information>
            </textContent>
            <controlAuthority xlink:href="#AUTHOR01" xlink:arcrole="http://www.iho.int/s123/gml/1.0/roles/controlAuthority"/>
            <geometry>
                <S100:surfaceProperty>
                    <S100:Surface gml:id="NAVARE01.S">
                        <gml:patches>
                            <gml:PolygonPatch>
                                <gml:exterior>
                                    <gml:LinearRing>
                                        <gml:posList>60.7667 -32.6333 60.7667 -32.3167 61.3333 -32.3167 61.3333 -32.6333 60.7667 -32.6333</gml:posList>
                                    </gml:LinearRing>
                                </gml:exterior>
                            </gml:PolygonPatch>
                        </gml:patches>
                    </S100:Surface>
                </S100:surfaceProperty>
            </geometry>
        </S123:NavigationalMeteorologicalArea>
    </member>
    <member>
        <S123:RadioServiceArea gml:id="RDOSVC">
            <categoryOfBroadcastCommunication>commercial</categoryOfBroadcastCommunication>
            <radiocommunications>
                <categoryOfRadioMethods>Medium Frequency (MF) voice traffic</categoryOfRadioMethods>
                <signalFrequency>720</signalFrequency>
                <transmissionContent>Gale warning, High sea forecast, weather reports from coast stations and the coastal forecast.</transmissionContent>
            </radiocommunications>
            <serviceProvider xlink:href="#RDOSTA01" xlink:arcrole="http://www.iho.int/s123/gml/1.0/roles/serviceProvider"/>
            <geometry>
                <S100:surfaceProperty>
                    <S100:Surface gml:id="RDOSVC.S">
                        <gml:patches>
                            <gml:PolygonPatch>
                                <gml:exterior>
                                    <gml:LinearRing>
                                        <gml:posList>60.7667 -32.6333 60.7667 -32.3167 61.3333 -32.3167 61.3333 -32.6333 60.7667 -32.6333</gml:posList>
                                    </gml:LinearRing>
                                </gml:exterior>
                            </gml:PolygonPatch>
                        </gml:patches>
                    </S100:Surface>
                </S100:surfaceProperty>
            </geometry>
        </S123:RadioServiceArea>
    </member>
    <member>
        <S123:GMDSSArea gml:id="GMDSSA01">
            <categoryOfGMDSSArea>Area A1</categoryOfGMDSSArea>
            <geometry>
                <S100:surfaceProperty>
                    <S100:Surface gml:id="GMDSSA01.S">
                        <gml:patches>
                            <gml:PolygonPatch>
                                <gml:exterior>
                                    <gml:LinearRing>
                                        <gml:posList>60.7667 -32.6333 60.7667 -32.3167 61.3333 -32.3167 61.3333 -32.6333 60.7667 -32.6333</gml:posList>
                                    </gml:LinearRing>
                                </gml:exterior>
                            </gml:PolygonPatch>
                        </gml:patches>
                    </S100:Surface>
                </S100:surfaceProperty>
            </geometry>
        </S123:GMDSSArea>
    </member>
    <member>
        <S123:RadioStation gml:id="RDOSTA01">
            <featureName>
                <language>eng</language>
                <name>Jussland Radio MW (Pastilledezan)</name>
            </featureName>
            <textContent>
                <information>
                    <language>eng</language>
                    <text>Broadcast from Pastilledezan on 774Khz (MW)</text>
                </information>
            </textContent>
            <radiocommunications>
                <signalFrequency>774000</signalFrequency>
            </radiocommunications>
            <serviceArea xlink:href="#RDOSVC01" xlink:arcrole="http://www.iho.int/s123/gml/1.0/roles/serviceArea"/>
            <geometry>
                <S100:pointProperty>
                    <S100:Point gml:id="RDOSTA01.P">
                        <gml:pos>60.9333369 -32.50765</gml:pos>
                    </S100:Point>
                </S100:pointProperty>
            </geometry>
        </S123:RadioStation>
    </member>
    <member>
        <S123:QualityOfNonBathymetricData gml:id="MNQUAL01">
            <categoryOfTemporalVariation>unlikely to change</categoryOfTemporalVariation>
            <dataAssessment>assessed</dataAssessment>
            <horizontalPositionalUncertainty>
                <uncertaintyFixed>-1</uncertaintyFixed>
            </horizontalPositionalUncertainty>
            <geometry>
                <S100:surfaceProperty>
                    <S100:Surface gml:id="MNQUAL01.S">
                        <gml:patches>
                            <gml:PolygonPatch>
                                <gml:exterior>
                                    <gml:LinearRing>
                                        <gml:posList>60.7667 -32.6333 60.7667 -32.3167 61.3333 -32.3167 61.3333 -32.6333 60.7667 -32.6333</gml:posList>
                                    </gml:LinearRing>
                                </gml:exterior>
                            </gml:PolygonPatch>
                        </gml:patches>
                    </S100:Surface>
                </S100:surfaceProperty>
            </geometry>
        </S123:QualityOfNonBathymetricData>
    </member>
    <member>
        <S123:DataCoverage gml:id="M_COVR01">
            <maximumDisplayScale>24999</maximumDisplayScale>
            <minimumDisplayScale>1499999</minimumDisplayScale>
            <geometry>
                <S100:surfaceProperty>
                    <S100:Surface gml:id="M_COVR01.S">
                        <gml:patches>
                            <gml:PolygonPatch>
                                <gml:exterior>
                                    <gml:LinearRing>
                                        <gml:posList>60.7667 -32.6333 60.7667 -32.3167 61.3333 -32.3167 61.3333 -32.6333 60.7667 -32.6333</gml:posList>
                                    </gml:LinearRing>
                                </gml:exterior>
                            </gml:PolygonPatch>
                        </gml:patches>
                    </S100:Surface>
                </S100:surfaceProperty>
            </geometry>
        </S123:DataCoverage>
    </member>
</S123:Dataset>
```